# Oracle Data Sort By Date and Time

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle database. Below is Equipment working Time Sheet details which is always start from morning 7:00 AM and end on next day 7:00 AM (total 24 hours) . I need report in same way with date wise ascending and Time From 7:00 AM to next day 7:00 AM. Please advise on same.

WorkDate is Date type and rest two column are varchar2 type

```
CREATE TABLE TT
(
 WorkDate DATE,
 FromTime VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
 ToTime   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)

)

Work date   From    To
8/8/2017    7:00    7:25
8/8/2017    7:25    12:35
8/8/2017    12:35   21:55
8/8/2017    21:55   1:30
8/8/2017    1:30    7:00
8/9/2017    7:00    7:25
8/9/2017    7:25    12:35
8/9/2017    12:35   21:55
8/9/2017    21:55   1:30
8/9/2017    1:30    7:00
```

Comment: What type(s) are the these columns? Can you share your table's DDL?

Comment: WorkDate is Date type and rest is varchar2

Comment: Why did you tag your question with the Microsoft SQL Server tag if you are using Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the only problem is that `7:25` comes after `12:35` in the alphabet. You need `07:25` instead. Use `LPAD` for this:

```
select *
from mytable
order by workdate, lpad(fromtime, 5, '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the date with the from time, then cast to a date to sort the result set.

```
select * from tt
order by to_date(to_char(work_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') || ' ' || from_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
/
```

The easiest thing would have been to store the FROM and TO as datetimes but no doubt there are good reasons why your application needs to do things the hard way.